# Windows 10 (unlike Win7) keeps losing index of mounted (virtual) drive

Tags: windows-10, truecrypt, search-indexing

For years I have been mounting virtual drives at logon (encrypted drives which are TrueCrypt files). In the drive properties, I set Indexing to `ON`. Windows 7 used to index those drives properly.

While Windows 10 will build the index, when I restart the machine, the index for the drive is gone (these files no longer appear in Windows search). Also, the drive doesn't appear in Indexing Options, except at the times when I click *Rebuild* in Indexing Options.

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

- *Rebuild* in Indexing Options. This works, but I don't 
  want to do that with each restart.
- On the Desktop, I have made a folder that contains symbolic links to the encrypted drives. Since the Desktop is indexed, I was hoping that the drives would be indexed.
- Indexing Troubleshooting. This seemed to fix some permissions but the problem remains.

If I can't get it to work, I'll have to kill Windows Indexing and spend hours evaluating third-party software -- not looking forward to that.

Switching away from TrueCrypt drives is not an option I am willing to consider at the moment.

Would someone have insights on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

At https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ it says:

> In order to be able to index a VeraCrypt volume through Windows Search, the volume must be mounted at boot time (System Favorite) or the Windows Search services must be restart after the volume is mounted. This is needed because Windows Search can only index drives that are available when it starts.

Try to restart the service: Run: services.msc > 'Windows Search' > Restart

Or from command line, with admin privileges:

```
net stop wsearch
net start wsearch
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thank you. I already have a BAT file that waits for Dropbox, Thunderbird and other applications to start. Adding in `net stop wsearch /y` and `net start wsearch` has worked. Also had to run as administratior. Which required a BAT file to run a LNK file (as admin) to run a BAT file. Convoluted, but the startup folder wouldn't run a LNK file set to run as an admin. Hence the series of files.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same trouble, here is my painless(ish) workaround, haven't found anything better so far:

1. having **shortcut on desktop** to .bat file with "run as admin" option, which I run every time after mounting an image **to restart search service**:

   :stop
   sc stop WSearch
   ping 127.0.0.1 -n 4 -w 1000 > nul
   sc query WSearch | find /I "STATE" | find "STOPPED"
   if errorlevel 1 goto :stop
   goto :start

   :start
   sc start WSearch

- found it on some forum, it's a bit complicated, but more reliable than just start/stop.

2. now I have mounted drive in indexed locations, but search from start menu (or startisback, which is much more pleasing for my eyes) doesn't return results or shows too few of them.
   so now I go to stock win 10 start, where I have pinned shortcut **to windows search options** (the new win 10 menu, not the one mentioned in OP), where I **switch from classic search style to extended and then right back** (or leave it as it is, main idea is to switch mode). now it starts working as intended and shows full search results.

Answer (score 0):

Extended search might not be enough for encrypted volumes. Neither setting VeraCrypt mount to the drive letter instead of volume id.

My solution (yes, SOLVED) was to check "Index encrypted files". This setting is in pretty unobvious and longish location:

Search settings -> Searching Windows -> Advanced Search Indexer Settings (Indexing options -dialogue) -> Advanced Options -> File Settings / Index encrypted files (checkbox, set this on)

After this (but not before even if I tried many things) my VeraCrypt volume appears to the Indexed Locations dialogue where it can be checked in to the selected locations list. This dialogue can be found from the almost same path:

Search settings -> Searching Windows -> Advanced Search Indexer Settings (Indexing options -dialogue) -> Modify (Indexed Locations dialogue appears)